# unable to include logged in user id in url(address bar)

Tags: php, mysql, server

I'm trying to echo user id to be displayed in url [view db structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8mec.png) when a user is logged in to a system much like abc.php?uid=5 (Reason is, I need the logged in user id to be passed when a logged in user makes a post so as to use their user_id to display their details in a feeds view page) I've tried various codes but unable to achieve it. When I run the code below, there's no reaction, just stuck at the log in page. Pls I need help.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
   include_once('queryclass.php');



  $error = false;
  if(isset($_POST['btn-login'])){
  $username = trim($_POST['username']);
  $username = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($username));

  $password = trim($_POST['password']);
  $password = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($password));


   if(empty($username)){
    $error = true;
    $errorUsername = 'Please Input Username';
  }

  if(empty($password)){
    $error = true;
    $errorPassword = 'Please Input Password';       
   }elseif(strlen($password)< 6){
    $error = true;
    $errorPassword = 'Password must be at least six characters';
   }    

  if(!$error){


        $password = md5($password);
    $sql = "select * from company where username='$username' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if($count==1 && $row['password'] == $password){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        function do_user_directory(){
        $users = $this->load_all_user_objects();
        foreach($users as $user){?>
        header('location: loggedin.php?uid=<?php echo $user->id;?>');            
        <?php
        }
        }
    }else{
        $errorMsg = 'Invalid Username or Password';
    }
    }

    }


    ?>


   This is the queryclass.php

  <?php 
  require_once('connectdb.php');

  function load_user_object($user_id){
  global $db;

  $table = 'users';

  $query = "
              SELECT * FROM $table
              WHERE ID = $user_id
           ";

   $obj = $db->select($query);
    if(!$obj) {
        return "No user found";
     }

    return $obj[0];

   }

   function load_all_user_objects(){
   global $db;

   $table = 'users';

     $query = "
              SELECT * FROM $table

           ";

   $obj = $db->select($query);

    if(!$obj) {
        return "No user found";
     }

     return $obj;

   }


   ?>
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but please look up php sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: why not just keep user id in `$_SESSION['uid']` and operate with that data without passing it from `$_GET` array ?

Comment: its a prototype... I'm quite aware of what you pointed out.

Comment: so there is no much work to do prototype correct from the beginning

Comment: I just don't understand why You retrieve whole users table when user logs in by doing  `$this->load_all_user_objects();`  and redirecting him to somewhere? what if table will have 10000 rows?

Answer (score 0):

So let's just keep that id in `$_SESSION` too:

```
// building query to users table (sanitizing Your inputs from sql injections)
$q = "SELECT ID, username FROM users WHERE ";
$q.= " username='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username)."' AND ";
$q.= " password='".md5($password)."' LIMIT 1";

$r = @mysqli_fetch_assoc(@mysqli_query($conn, $q));
if(is_array($r) AND !empty($)) { // in case of success $r will keep user array
    $_SESSION['user'] = $r;      // same as doing $_SESSION['user'] = ['ID' => 1, 'username' => 'somebody'];
    session_write_close();       // closing session (commiting changes)
    header('Location: loggedin.php'); // redirecting user to loggedin.php     
    exit(0);                     // preventing php script to go down to not execute other statements below
}
```

and somewhere in `loggedin.php`

do guarding like:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
  header('Location: logout.php');
  exit(0);
}
```

get authenticated user's id like:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user']['ID'];
```

if You want to echo user id in somewhere in html just do for example like:

```
<?php $user_id = $_SESSION['user'] ? $_SESSION['user']['ID'] : 'default'; ?>
<img src="/uploads/users/<?=$user_id?>.jpg">
```

Comment: hi, its more like using the user_id to retrieve logged in user information in a feeds view php page...just like twitter or facebook feeds page.

Answer (score -1):

In query class. Php query statement use single quotes as = '$user_rid'